# Create .env file for database connection

Tags: php

I have created an **.env** file and I am going to pull the vars from the **includes/database/config.php** file to connect to the database.
The code:

```
<?php

require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

$dotenv = \Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__ . '../../../');
$dotenv->load();

$localhost = $_ENV["LOCALHOST"];
$username = $_ENV["NAME"];
$password = $_ENV["PASSWORD"];
$database = $_ENV["DATABASE"];

var_dump($username);

?>
```

but during my debug it comes out

> Warning: Undefined array key "USERNAME" NULL

No idea

Comment: So it means there is not `USERNAME` in your `$_ENV`. How does your `.env` look like?

Answer (score -1):

I just updated my post. I found the right solution and I share it in case someone else has the same problem.
For some reason the word USERNAME" was binding. I changed it with the word "NAME", and it worked fine

Comment: You can answer yourself and mark the answer as accepted so that future users can identify the problem you encountered as solved.